# firefox window size and position

Tags: firefox, window

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with a dual monitor setup.

I like Firefox to have a specific position and size on my screen. So I resize it and position it like I want it. But when I close and reopen it, it randomly resizes and positions itself as it wants.

Is there a way to make Firefox remember it's size and position?  I have tried compizconfig settings manager but this changes the default behavior of all firefox windows, including pop up dialog boxes.  I'm hoping there is a better method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve the fundamental problem, but if the position you prefer is a simple one, like maximized or one third of the screen horizontally, then QuickTile might be able to help you. [Have look at it here.](http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/) You will need to add `/path/to/script --daemonize` as a startup application.